# Error 400 on "get css googleapis error"

Tags: css, wordpress

I have wrecked my brains to find the error to no avail. Pingdom tools and every other speed page tester shows a connection error 400 get css fonts.googleapis.com
Theme developers have no idea. The site is using wordpress. I have tried disabling all the plugins. Still get the error. How can I tell which file is causing the error?

Comment: look for the file containing code for google fonts

Comment: I did that already. A lot of them contain code for google fonts.

Comment: There is no way to tell which file is calling it.